# How to make text float over column when moused over?

Tags: html, css

I want to make some text float over the column edge when I mouse-over it, just like my IDE does:

[image]

[Here's what I've got so far](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/p7fCx/1/).

I can get it to float over the edge if I change the element positioning to `absolute` but then it doesn't "take up any space".

Also, I wouldn't mind having the border around the floated bit either.

Anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a go at it and have come up with a solution which does not require any mark up changes at all, I have done some testing and it seems to work in **Chrome 26**, **Safari 5.1.7**, **Firefox 20**, **IE10**, **IE10 in IE9 mode** and **IE10 in IE8 mode**, it looks the same in all of these browsers and browser modes, it starts to break when using **IE10 in IE7 mode**.

It looks like this:

[image: Text floating over the column edge]

Basically what I've done is setting `float:left` on the `li` and then `width:auto` on `li:hover`, this ensures that the text floats over the column edge.

Then to add the border, I'm rendering a pseudo-element directly after the `li`, which inherits the width of the preceding `li`. Then I've set its borders, margins, heights and line-heights to position this pseudo-element over the top of the preceding `li`. I've set the `margin-left` to `150px` to ensure it only shows up behind `li`'s which exceed the width of the column.

To add some space at the right I have changed the `white-space: no-wrap` to `white-space: pre`, which will preserve some added white space inside the `li` (if it is added, it is not a requirement, I did add it to make it look a little prettier).

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3TCy/3/).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>some really long text </li>
    <li>some text that doesn't fit into the column width </li>
    <li>yeah dude, this is sample text </li>
    <li>woot woot! double rainbows </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
li {
  white-space: pre;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  line-height: 21px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
li:hover:after {
  content:'';
  height: 19px;
  margin: -21px 0px 0px 150px;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
}
li:hover {
  width: auto;
}
div {
  width:155px;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
ul:before, ul:after {
  content:' ';
  display: table;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have included the [Micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) on the `div`, now it adjusts its height based on its contents instead of it having a fixed height.

**UPDATE 2**

The problem with scrolling is that the width of the containing element is actually changing when setting `width:auto` on the child elements, since the scroll bar is on the right, it keeps moving around. I've tried using an extra wrapper `div`, but it seems that it is impossible to float stuff over the top of a scroll bar, from anywhere inside the element that creates the scroll bar. The only way I can get it to scroll is by setting `overflow:hidden` on the `ul` and then using the [jQuery ScrollTo](http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin to scroll up and down inside the `ul`.

[Example jsFiddle with scrolling](http://jsfiddle.net/r3TCy/11/)

Comment: My pleasure, see my update for a fix, the `div` does now adjust its size based on its contents.

Comment: Just a couple more things I'm trying to work out. (1) Is it possible to get this to work if the `<div>` has a scrollbar? http://jsfiddle.net/r3TCy/4/ (2) Is it possible to add some additional padding on the right when it pops out? http://jsfiddle.net/r3TCy/5/ It looks fine in your example, but on mine the text is pretty much touching the border.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a scrolling example, what browser are you using? The bit that makes it look all right in all the browsers I've tested is the `white-space: pre;` on the `li` and the added white space inside the `li`. I would be interested to know in which browser that doesn't work. Adding padding doesn't work because the pseudo element is empty.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 26 on Ubuntu right now. Maybe I can use one of those custom scrollbars (http://goo.gl/YjlCt) for my needs? A thinner scrollbar would look nice where I need this anyway. Shame about the padding; I guess I have to throw a couple `nbsp`s on there then.

Comment: The problem with those custom scroll bar plugins is that they add  extra `div`'s with `overflow: hidden` around the `div`, which will make the floating text disappear again. You're probably better of doing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/r3TCy/14/, with jQuery's ScrollTo and MouseWheel plugin. You'll just need to add a progress indicator between the arrows. `&nbsp`'s would work for the padding.

Answer (score 6):

I've found two ways to support this. The first requires you add span tags inside each li but it seems to be working across all browsers. The second works with the markup exactly as you have it, but doesn't work in chrome and safari.

All browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/vkBqg/1/

This solution is extremely simple and basically comes down to:

```
li {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   width: 150px;
}

li:hover {
    overflow-x: visible;
}
```

All but webkit-based browsers (chrome,safari):

http://jsfiddle.net/aeARH/1/

This is much hackier and requires you to changing the width and display type of the li, then forcing it to break line. The li:hover looks something like this:

```
overflow-x: auto;
width:auto;
content:"\A";
display:inline;
```

The take away in both of these should be position:absolute doesn't work well when you're trying to preserve the natural ordering among elements.

Comment: I had the same solution, but I was setting `display: inline;` on the `li:hover span` instead of `width:auto;`. Not sure how we could add the borders however...